# Python+mySQL: How to insert data through Pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am trying to insert data into mysql database using pymysql but I always have this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank,face,regtime,spacesta,birthday,sign,level,OfficialVerifyType,OfficialVerify' at line 1")
```

Here's my code, I tried to write query in one line but still fail

```
                    cur = conn.cursor()
                    cur.execute('INSERT INTO bilibili_user_info(mid,name,sex,rank,face,regtime,spacesta,\
                                birthday,sign,level,OfficialVerifyType,OfficialVerifyDesc,vipType,vipStatus,\
                                toutu,toutuId,coins,following,fans,archiveview,article)\
                    VALUES ("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s",\
                            "%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s")'
                                %
                                (mid,name,sex,rank,face,regtime,spacesta,\
                                birthday,sign,level,OfficialVerifyType,OfficialVerifyDesc,vipType,vipStatus,\
                                toutu,toutuId,coins,following,fans,archiveview,article))
                    conn.commit()
```

Comment: `rank` is a reserved word in MySQL and must be enclosed in backticks: ```cur.execute('INSERT INTO bilibili_user_info(mid,name,sex,`rank`,face...```

Comment: I tried to enclose 'rank' but still no good,same syntax error

Comment: It can't be exactly the same error, can you post?

Comment: sorry my bad, I used the wrong type of backticks, problem solved, thx a lot !!!

Comment: No worries. I'm glad it's sorted